# Is there an advantage to using a task here

Tags: .net, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

I have a method that I am considering using a task to do some work. But is there really an advantage in this case? My reasoning was because the `CheckInToWebDocs` method is dependent on the presence of a file created by `SaveDocument`.

#### Without Task

```vb
 Private Sub PopulatePDF()
     Dim PrintLib As New Print
        Dim sPDFFilePath As String = ""
        If PrintLib.CreateEnrolledApp(EnrollmentID, sPDFFilePath) Then
           AppName = Page.ResolveUrl("~\SomeLocation\" & Path.GetFileName(sPDFFilePath))
           hlApplication.NavigateUrl = AppName

           SaveDocument(Constants.enumDocumentTypes.Application, EnrollmentID, Path.GetFileName(sPDFFilePath), sPDFFilePath)

           CheckInToWebDocs(EnrollmentID, sPDFFilePath)
        End If
    End Sub
```

#### Using Task

```vb
 Private Sub PopulatePDF()
        Dim PrintLib As New Print
        Dim sPDFFilePath As String = ""
        If PrintLib.CreateEnrolledApp(EnrollmentID, sPDFFilePath) Then
            AppName = Page.ResolveUrl("~\SomeLocation\" & Path.GetFileName(sPDFFilePath))
            hlApplication.NavigateUrl = AppName

            Dim saveDocumentTask As Task = Task.Run(Sub() SaveDocument(Constants.enumDocumentTypes.Application, EnrollmentID, Path.GetFileName(sPDFFilePath), sPDFFilePath))
            saveDocumentTask.Wait()

            CheckInToWebDocs(EnrollmentID, sPDFFilePath)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like it does IO (judging by the function names), so it could be a good candidate for `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the way you're using it.  It will add the overhead of a parallel task, but you'll still be bound waiting on the task to complete.

Is there an Async variant of `SaveDocument`? If so, then you could make your own `PopulatePDF()` method Async, calling `Await SaveDocumentAsync(...)` (if naming follows convention). Then any consumer of `PopulatePDF` could *also* be Async, including responses to UI events which give you the benefit I think you're looking for.

---

*Response to Comment*: That's a shame. What I would say in this case: there is still no benefit to adding `Task.Run` to your implementation. This can be tempting, but you need to be aware that this spawns a new thread. That is, if you do something like this:

```
Private Async Function PreparePdfAsync() As Task
  ...
  Await Task.Run(Sub() SaveDocument(...))
  ...
End Function
```

you're only getting *fake* asynchronous code--synchronous code running on a background thread. In a UI scenario, your best option is to let the UI consumer call `Task.Run()` themselves if they need to, don't wrap that detail away, because the thread-spawning is non-obvious and potentially deleterious behavior.

See Stephen Cleary for more info on [Task.Run etiquette](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) and be sure to read up on his other intro articles if you're new to Async/Await.

Comment: Unfortunately, the library that SaveDocument uses does not have any Async variants.